# ContactId of Case not populating at times

Tags: case, contact, postman

I use postman as a rest client to post a `case` with `supplied email` field populated, in the apex class what we do is we check if a `contact` exists with the email of the supplied email of the case, if it exists we assign this `contact` to the `contactId` to this `case`, else we create a new `contact` with the email as the supplied email of the case and then assign this `contact` to the `case`.

The problem is sometimes the `contactId` field is not getting populated and I have been asked to resolve it. I have so far created 50+ cases in the test sandbox and all of them got populated with `contactId`. I am unable to replicate the error. Is it a problem of session?

Comment: do you have error handling in that code? Maybe there is an unhandled error and therefor Contact is not created

Comment: yes there is error handling, but as I said I cannot replicate the error. I cannot see the debug logs of older cases with this problem because they are no longer there.